# Como centralizar layout

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Quero centralizar esse panel, mesmo quando a tela for maximizada, quero que ele continue centralizado. E não como está.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: use as propriedades Achor. Se quiser que ele aumente de acordo com o form, deixe todas marcadas, caso contrario desmarque todas

Comment: Eu não quero que aumente, quero que permaneça centralizado e do mesmo tamanho.

Comment: por isso o "caso contrário, desmarque todas." Como o colega respondeu abaixo, deixe como 'none'

Comment: De certo! Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nas propriedades do elemento, você irá localizar a opção *Layout* e definir o *Anchor* para *None*.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Deu certo! Muito Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

você tbm pode fazer via código:

Sabendo que o centro do Contêiner localiza-se na metade de sua largura .Width / 2 e na metade da sua altura .Heigth / 2

controle.Top = (Contêiner.Heigth / 2) - (controle.Heigth - 2);

controle.Left = (Contêiner.Width / 2) - (controle.width - 2);

Obs.: o Contêiner nada mais é, que seu recipiente.