# Como definir posição de objetos em form em tela cheia

Tags: c#

como definir aonde ficam cada componente do meu formulário quando ele fica em tela cheia. (Quanto você faz o form ele fica de um jeito, quanto você executa o form fica em tela cheia (como coloquei) mas os componentes nos se centralizaram ficam no lugar errado) Tem como resolver isso? VEJA NAS IMAGENS
[Como eu coloco os componenetes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jis3l.png)
[image: Como ela fica em tela cheia]

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como centralizar layout](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/261442/como-centralizar-layout)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize a propriedade Anchor como demonstro figura abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

passe esta propriedade Anchor para None deixando sem qualquer seleção dentro da propriedade.

Comment: Muito Obrigado Mesmo! Me ajudou Muito!